# What is SQLite's version-valid-for number?

Tags: sqlite

It has been confusing for me what the difference is between the version-vaild-for number (offset 92) and the file change counter (offset 96) in the database file header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entries at offsets 92 and 96 were added in later version of the SQLite library.

When an older version modifies the file, it will change the change counter (offset 24), but not adjust the version-valid-for number or the write library version number. So the library version number is no longer correct, because a different version last wrote to the file.

The version-valid-for number allows a new library to detect this case: if the change counter and the version-valid-for number do not match, then the write library version number is outdated, and must be ignored.